# How to incorporate an ANOVA into a "for loop" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am attempting to run an ANOVA on a number of variables from a list. However, I am having trouble letting indicating that the variable (variable 'lst) inside the ANOVA formula actually refers to a list.

Here is what I attempted:

```
lst = ['Item1', 'Item2']

for item in lst:
    mod = ols('lst ~ Group', data= DF).fit()
    aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod, typ=2)
    print(aov_table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accces the correspondig item in the for loop you have to format the string, using the `format()` method.
For example:

```
lst = ['Item1', 'Item2']

for item in lst:
    mod = ols('{} ~ Group'.format(item), data= DF).fit()
    aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(mod, typ=2)
    print(aov_table)
```

The formula string will be `Item1 ~ Group` for the first item and `Item2 ~ Group` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

A more expansive example where you have multiple DVs and IVs that you want to run, you could do a cartesian product of the items and use them in the model, like so:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import itertools

dvs = ['a', 'b']
ivs = ['d', 'e', 'f', ]
```

Calling `iterools.product(dvs, ivs)` will give you the product of the dvs and and ivs, like below:

```
a d
a e
a f
b d
b e
b f
```

So you full model will look like below:

```
aov = {} # collect the results in a dictionary
for dv, iv in itertools.product(dvs, ivs):
    model = ols('{} ~ C({})'.format(dv, iv), data=df).fit()
    aov[dv, iv] = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2) # use dv, iv as index
```

Finally, when you print `aov`, it will print the combo of (dv, iv) as keys to the data dict, and you can retrieve each of the results individually with

```
aov.get(('dv', 'iv')).style.format(precision=3) # this formats it nicely for you
```